# Can I program & run metro app for windows 8 using HTML5 on windows server 2012?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-server-2012

I need to learn to program Windows 8 "Windows Store" apps (formerly called Metro.) Instead of Windows 8, I have a license of Windows Server 2012. The question is, can I run and program Metro apps (written in HTML 5) on Windows Server 2012? I have Visual Studio 2012 I can install on the server.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't.
Metro apps is only suported for Windows 8.

You can install SDK [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx#Requirements) and run apps on emulator.

Comment: Thanks Nobert, that's useful. But I am still wondering after installing .Net Framework 4.5, aforementioned SDK & Visual Studio 2012, do I need to have any other emulator or provided with VS2012 for running apps during development will work ?

Comment: Emulator is included in Windows 8 SDK.

Comment: Thanks once again, Is this means I can program & debug Windows Store apps on Windows Server 2012 using emulator, but for actual running & user experience of apps, Windows 8 is needed?